# Eclipse on win64

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-3.4, ganymede

Is anyone successfully using the latest 64-bit Ganymede release of Eclipse on Windows XP or Vista 64-bit?

Currently I run the normal Eclipse 3.4 distribution on a 32bit JDK and launch & compile my apps with a 64bit JDK. Our previous experience has been that the 64bit Eclipse distro is unstable for us, so I'm curious if anyone is using it successfully.

We are using JDK 1.6.0_05.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using Eclipse with a 64bit VM. However I have to use Java 1.5, because with Java 1.6, even 1.6.0_10ea, Eclipse crashed when changing the .classpath-file. On Linux I had the same problems and could only get the 64bit Eclipse to work with 64bit Java 1.5.

The problem seems to be with the just in time compilation, since with vmparam -Xint eclipse works -- but this is not a sollution, because it's slow then.

**Edit:**

With 1.6.0_11 it seems to work.

1.6_10 final might work as well as mentioned in the comment, but I've not tested that.

Comment: JDK 1.5 or 1.6.0_10 (now out of beta) appear to be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

I've been successfully using it on Vista x64 for some light Java work.  Nothing too involved and no extra plugins, but basic Java coding has been working without any issues.  I'm using the 3.4M7 build but it looks like the [3.4 stable build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.4-200806172000/index.php) supports Vista x64 now.